# Automatically add rules to iptables when an user logs in or logs out with ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables

I'm looking for a solution to automatically add couple of rules to iptables when an user logs in and remove those rules when it logs out.

I'd like to get somehow get the ip address of the user from the ssh connection and use it.

Anyone has a tip for me on how to achieve this?

Comment: It might help if you told us what in particular you were trying to achieve by doing this.  Are you trying to give the SSH user access to different ports than the general public, for example?

Comment: I would start looking to into pam modules.  I am almost certain there are pam modules that can execute things when a user authenticates.

Comment: @Katherine, Yes, basically I'm trying limit access to a specific port just for autheticated users

Comment: @Zoredache, yes, I could use pam_exec, I was thinking there is a more elegant solution

Comment: Not sure what you think is inelegant about something like pam_exec?  Does these changes need to happen for any ssh connection (as in scp/sftp/etc), or is it limited to interactive sessions?  Can you simply put something in your your shell profile `/etc/profile.d`?

Comment: Perhaps using iptables's ability to match based on local user/uid would be useful here. That would be more permanent than asked for though.

Comment: I've been reading more about pam and it looks like I can get it done with pam_exec or pam_script. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Depending on the timeframe (is a second or so OK ?) you may be able to use fail2ban - Fail2Ban reads a given logfile as its write and takes actions you configure it to do (including adding iptables rules if you desire).